# What does regex (#,?,:)[a-zA-Z0-9]*_* mean?

Tags: .net, regex

I have some old .NET codes that searching for parameter in a sql string

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection collection =
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(icmd.CommandText, 
"(#,?,:)[a-zA-Z0-9]*_*");
```

I don't know how it matches. Can anyone explain me?

Comment: Not the solution to your question, but I suspect the `(#,?,:)` section is in error and should actually be `[#?:]`.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right, It help me alot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See below diagram explaining it.

[image]

UPDATE: In below code `#,,:abc12_` is a match.

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection collection =
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches("#,,:abc12_", "(#,?,:)[a-zA-Z0-9]*_*");
```

Comment: for future reference, what application did you generate the diagram with?

Comment: Its for Javascript but works with other languages too... http://www.regexper.com/

Answer (score 3):

Refer **[this](http://regex101.com/)** for any doubt in regex .

In    `(#,?,:)[a-zA-Z0-9]*_*`

```
1st Capturing group (#,?,:)
# matches the character # literally
,? matches the character , literally
Quantifier: Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

,: matches the characters ,: literally
[a-zA-Z0-9]* match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
A-Z a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9


_* matches the character _ literally
Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
```

Means : it can match `#,,:anycharactorstring` , `#,,:anycharactorstring_` , `#,:anycharactorstring` , `#,:anycharactorstring_____` etc.